# Trocando API do projeto

Tags: android, api, visual-studio, datepicker, xamarin.android

Erro sempre que troco da API 24 para API 15, API 16 ou API 19.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse recurso existe nas versões anteriores da api ?

Comment: Acredito que o **Theme.AppCompat** é só da API 21 em diante

Comment: Acredito que só a partir da API 21 (eu também tentei essa e da o mesmo problema). Na verdade eu gostaria de saber como que troco a API do projeto Android... ou se tem uma forma em que ao criar projeto já crie com a API 15 por exemplo, uma configuração padrão ou algo assim...

Answer (score 0):

Para mudar a API destinada do projeto

1. Clique duas vezes em `Properties`
2. Na mesma seção `Aplication` escolha a API destinada

**Segue o Screenshot**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Outra coisa a se levar em conta seria os pacotes NuGet que você esta utilizando,alguns são compativeis somente com a  API 21 pra cima